# Why doesn't my formidable code work with node js (upload an image and have the code respond according to the user's action)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, formidable

I'm watching [bluuweb's node course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iU3mnrw48I0&list=PLCB86r2r1iKKmz21UIlZjQieBF7ljb6Qu&index=80) and in it they do a practical exercise.

This is the code for minute 39 specifically:

```
const formidable = require("formidable");

const cambiarFotoPerfil = (req, res) => {
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.maxFileSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;

    form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {

        try {
            
            if (err) {
                throw new Error('Falló formidable')
            }

            console.log(fields);
            console.log(files.myFile)

            const file = files.myFile;

            if(file.originalFilename === ""){
                throw new Error('No se seleccionó ninguna imagen')
            }
            
            if(!['image/jpeg', 'image/png'].includes(file.mimetype)){
                throw new Error('Por favor agrega una imagen con formato .jpg o png')
            }

            if(file.size > 5 * 1024 * 1024){
                throw new Error('La imagen debe ser de máximo 5MB')
            }

            req.flash("mensajes", [{ msg: "Ya se subió la imagen" }]);
            return res.redirect('/perfil');
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            req.flash("mensajes", [{ msg: error.message }]);
            return res.redirect("/perfil");
        }
    });
};

module.exports = {
    formPerfil,
    cambiarFotoPerfil
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<form action="/perfil?_csrf={{csrfToken}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{!-- <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}" /> --}}
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mb-2" type="file" id="formFileSm" name="myFile" />
    <button class="btn btn-dark">Cambiar foto</button>
</form>
```

The problem is that if I don't send any files it jumps to the error 'Failed great' and ignores the rest. And when I send a `jpg` or `png` file I get the error `Please add an image in .jpg or png format`, although it is supposed to comply with the format.

I tried to remove the following code

```
if (err) {
      throw new Error('Falló formidable')
}
```

but it jumped to an error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'originalFilename')

I also tried uninstalling formidable and reinstalling it but nothing changed. I don't know if it's a syntax problem or a formidable bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution to my question

Finally I found a solution. In `const file = files.myFile[0];` I added the `[0]`.

**This is my new script:**

```
const {formidable} = require("formidable");

const cambiarFotoPerfil = (req, res) => {

    const form = formidable({});
    form.maxFileSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB

    form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) {
            req.flash("mensajes", [{ msg: "Falló formidable" }]);
            return res.redirect("/perfil");
        }
    
        // HERE the [0] was added as mentioned above
        const file = files.myFile[0];

        try {
            // console.log(fields);
            console.log(file)

            console.log(file.originalFilename)

            if(file.originalFilename === ""){
                throw new Error('No se seleccionó ninguna imagen')
            }
            
            if(!['image/jpeg', 'image/png'].includes(file.mimetype)){
                throw new Error('Por favor agrega una imagen con formato .jpg o png')
            }

            if(file.size > 5 * 1024 * 1024){
                throw new Error('La imagen debe ser de máximo 5MB')
            }

            req.flash("mensajes", [{ msg: "Ya se subió la imagen" }]);
            return res.redirect('/perfil');
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            req.flash("mensajes", [{ msg: error.message }]);
            return res.redirect("/perfil");
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as the correct answer if this is the solution to your question.